# Laravel 8 - Envoyer & Homestead Deployment Issues

Tags: laravel, github, deployment, homestead, envoyer.io

So I am using Laravel Homestead for my local development. I opted to install it per-project rather than globally so that all of my Homestead configuration files would be tracked in my git repository. To keep my repository clean, I opted to place the entirety of the Laravel application into a sub-directory named 'code'.

This, however, has presented me with a challenge when attempting to deploy my application via Envoyer. It seems as though Envoyer assumes the Laravel application files are in the root directory of the repository. As such, when it attempts to deploy it fails.

I've been searching around and can't seem to find any way of specifying to Envoyer that my Laravel application files are not in the root directory of the repository but are in the 'code' directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Repository Structure:

```
/
  - Homestead related files
  - /code
    - Laravel application files
```